# AWS SAM Local and docker-lambda: keep getting Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

**Edit 2: The root cause was I had several DOCKER environment variables set which were causing my function invocations to re-route to a remote Docker host and not hit SAM Local. Once I unset those, the functions started running.**

Edit: I cloned docker-lambda and tried running one of their examples and get the same error.

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/var/task lambci/lambda:python3.6
START RequestId: 73a433fc-1d8a-4cdb-a66d-61bd667e13ba Version: $LATEST
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'
END RequestId: 73a433fc-1d8a-4cdb-a66d-61bd667e13ba
REPORT RequestId: 73a433fc-1d8a-4cdb-a66d-61bd667e13ba Duration: 1 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1536 MB Max Memory Used: 15 MB

{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"}
```

I'm trying to set up SAM Local with a Python lambda function and keep getting frustrated by the module import error in the title.

My template.yaml looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  ProposalsTable:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::SimpleTable"
  AddProposal:
    Type: "AWS::Serverless::Function"
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TABLE_NAME: !Ref ProposalsTable
      Events:
        Vote:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /proposals
            Method: get
```

I have a lambda_function.py in the same folder as the template.yaml.

I run: `sam local start-api` and it starts up fine:

```
Mounting lambda_function.lambda_handler (python3.6) at http://127.0.0.1:3000/proposals [GET]
```

Then I do:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3000/proposals
```

Then on the "server" it shows:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'
Function returned an invalid response (must include one of: body, headers or statusCode in the response object): %!s(<nil>)
```

I've tried all different ways of naming the file (e.g. putting it inside a folder with an **init**.py)

I googled and read a dozen or more threads but most people are talking about deploying to the real AWS Lambda; there's not a lot on SAM Local.

I wonder if it's something in my environment. The node.js sample function here fails with a timeout. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/tree/develop/samples/hello-world/node

```
2018/01/04 15:20:41 Invoking index.handler (nodejs6.10)
2018/01/04 15:20:41 Mounting /Users/me/code/sam-local-prototype as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
2018/01/04 15:20:46 Function index.handler timed out after 3 seconds
```

Ideas?

Comment: I think you are getting a timeout from the example code because the `event.json` in that repo appears to be invalid (at least from my experience with SAM). I wrote [this](https://github.com/NZenitram/s3-lambda-html-parser/blob/master/event.json) last week, and I use it today. It works, and is written in python. I use `sam local invoke "S3" --event event.json` to initialize the docker env, and run it another window again to trigger the event. The `event.json` in my case triggers a real event on the bucket I have configured.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure that it's even getting to the point of ingesting an event.json. It doesn't seem to be executing the function at all.

Comment: You might be right, but I believe that IP is important. If I am connected to my work VPN and run the same event it times out. You will also see in the `template.yaml` file in my repo I renamed the `Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler` to `Handler: lambda.lambda_handler` to match the name of the file it will be running. `sam local invoke "S3"` also matches the value of the `Resources` Key.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: No, sir, I have not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'lambda_function'` error:

In the repo link you provided within the `template.yaml` the Handler key reads: `Handler: index.handler`. This corresponds to the `index.js` file that contains the function named `handler` written as `exports.handler = () => {}`

If you are re-writing this in Python, your `template.yaml` handler key will need to read `Handler: {file_name}.{function_name}`. If the file carrying your lambda function is called `lambda.py` and the function within it is `def lambda_handler` you will need to write your handler key in the `.yaml` as `Handler:lambda.lambda_function`. I remember having to modify the `key` beneath `Resources` but give make sure your file name and function name are accurate and try again.

I just copied the code out of the repo and ran it successfully. Do you have docker installed correctly? Or did you have `sam local api` started when you tried to run the test code from the repo? If it attempted to connect on the same port, you may get the timeout as well.

```
2018/01/16 13:39:14 Successfully parsed template.yaml
2018/01/16 13:39:14 Connected to Docker 1.35
2018/01/16 13:39:14 Runtime image missing, will pull....
2018/01/16 13:39:14 Fetching lambci/lambda:nodejs6.10 image for nodejs6.10 runtime...
nodejs6.10: Pulling from lambci/lambda
f338a32fa56c: Already exists 
4926b20b634f: Already exists 
8040e979acbc: Pull complete 
160b6838355f: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:e34f92bc0df0cf4a8ba560c6c7bf201183d5f6773ddf44440a97295486906744
Status: Downloaded newer image for lambci/lambda:nodejs6.10
2018/01/16 13:39:28 Invoking index.handler (nodejs6.10)
2018/01/16 13:39:28 Mounting /Users/me/sam_local_test as /var/task:ro inside runtime container
START RequestId: 8970d865-2d59-1d54-0825-d56f1fd035f7 Version: $LATEST
2018-01-16T20:39:32.315Z    8970d865-2d59-1d54-0825-d56f1fd035f7    LOG: Name is Bob
END RequestId: 8970d865-2d59-1d54-0825-d56f1fd035f7
REPORT RequestId: 8970d865-2d59-1d54-0825-d56f1fd035f7  Duration: 22.02 ms  Billed Duration: 0 ms   Memory Size: 0 MB   Max Memory Used: 28 MB  

"Hello Bob"
```

Comment: I wonder if it's a Docker issue. I do have some Docker stuff running in the background that I suppose could be interfering. Not 100% sure you mean by "it attempted to connect on the same port"

Comment: The `sam local invoke "HelloWorld" -e event.json` command is going to spin up a docker container and communicate with it. I am curious if that communication is done on the same port as `sam local api`.

Comment: Yeah, my dev environment has a custom export DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_CERT_PATH. I wonder if it's interfering. You may be on to something. Let me get back to you.

Comment: I tried unsetting my DOCKER env variables and I'm getting the same errors. :-(

Comment: It must be an ENV issue though right? Mine worked out of the box and I have not once touched a Docker config.

Comment: You got it working? I am confused by the bounty/check mark.

Comment: Sorry, I replied to the wrong area. Here: "Holy crap it worked. I did unset in my terminal for DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY... it's because I was re-routing Docker. I'll give you bounty" I needed to make sure I did the unset commands in each Terminal window too.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron,

Check out this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaCbIFH_d9k

You have listed:

- Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
- Is your file called lambda_function?
- Where is this file located? This matters because the element "CodeUri:" is where you specify the path to the file and I don't see that element in your explanation. Or if you zip up the project you can specify the file name here. For example I zip my project up then within the template.yml I specify my CodeUri to point to the zip as such:

  CodeUri: lambda.zip

.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I named the file lambda_function.py. CodeUri doesn't apply because this isn't being deployed to lambda yet -- this is SAM Local. I tried it anyway but it made no difference. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you share your function?

Comment: I'm just doing a modified version of the one here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-sam-local-beta-build-and-test-serverless-applications-locally/

Comment: I wonder if it's something in my environment. The node.js sample function here fails with a timeout. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/tree/develop/samples/hello-world/node

Comment: try this example :
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local/tree/develop/samples/hello-world/python

Comment: I looked at those and they're failing too. Both Node and Python. Python is just the same error: Unable to import module 'main': No module named 'main'. I have main.py in the project dir. The command line I use is `sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" -e event.json`

Comment: sounds like a path issue.

Comment: Could be. What's really interesting is I cloned the docker-lambda repo (upon which SAM Local is based) and it's spitting out the same error on their example lambda. I'll update this question to reflect that.

Comment: Holy crap it worked. I did unset in my terminal for DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_HOST and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY... it's because I was re-routing Docker. I'll give you bounty